# Downloading file made with jquery's .innerhtml breaks at the first "#"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function download()
{
    var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    a.download = "CalExport.svg";

    var dd = document.getElementById('SvgResult');
    alert(dd.innerHTML); //displays fine

    a.href = "data:image/svg+xml," + dd.innerHTML;
    a.click();//downloaded file cuts off at the first "#"
}
```

When the alert displays it it's okay, the downloaded version is cut off before the first "#". How do I fix this?

Comment: You have tagged this question with jQuery, we can utilise it and can you create a snippet for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is part of a href, you need to url-encode your data first, eg.

```
function download()
{
    var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    a.download = "CalExport.svg";

    var dd = document.getElementById('SvgResult');
    alert(dd.innerHTML); //should still display fine

    a.href = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(dd.innerHTML);
    a.click();//should now not cut off.
}
```

The safe variation of `#` in a url is `%23%0A` (check out this tool: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Comment: If you liked the answer, an upvote would also be appreciated :)